# Complex reporting PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel

I have four tables in my Database:

```
Metrics
->id
->description

Agents
->id
->name

Forms
->id
->agent_id
->campaign_id
->calldatetime
->phone

Forms_Responses
->id
->form_id
->metrics_id
->response
```

And one of the users asked me make a report like so:

```
Metric ID | Agent_name | Agent_name | Agent_name .. and so on (depends how many from db)
__________|____________|____________|______________
          |            |            |
1         | 90%        | 80%        | 70%
__________|____________|____________|_______________
2         | 80%        | 100%       | 50%
```

The report scales horizontally and vertically. Horizontally by `Agent_ID`

To get the Horizontal scalling (Columns) I have this query

```
SELECT a.id, b.name FROM forms a
INNER JOIN agents b ON a.agent_id = b.id
WHERE a.calldatetime >= '2015-12-12 00:00:00' 
AND a.calldatetime <= '2015-12-17 23:00:37' AND campaign_id = 22 GROUP BY agent_id ORDER BY id ASC;
```

I have `GROUP BY agent_id` so won't have a duplicate data. However my problem is on the `ROWS` . So Far I have

```
select form_id, metrics_id, response, remarks
from forms_responses 
where form_id >= 6951 and form_id <= 6953 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Don't mind the `where form_id >= 6951 and form_id <= 6953` . So that should be my row? Problem is how can I link that in my columns plus the values `90%, 80%..` is based from the formula

`Yes Counts / (Yes Counts + No Counts)` in the `response` column of the `Forms_Responses` table.

So basically this is a scoring report which get's the precentage for each agent on each metrics based on response value in the formula given.

I am doing this in Laravel PHP and will output as an excel with the format mentioned but I dunno what my queries will look like or how the processing goes or is it possbile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to get all of the agents in a single row. Just join the agents to the metrics and group by agent_id like you're doing. What's this unnecessary need to put agents in columns?

Comment: @Shadow Hi thanks for the suggestion but it's not duplicate of what you posted. I have a different scenario especially in the formulas in the values.

Comment: @trincot Edited. Sorry.

Comment: @Sherif That's the format of their report. Even if I want to change the format that's their requirements and for now I need to make it like that :(

Comment: @JoeneFloresca I think you misunderstand. I'm not saying don't generate your CSV report in that format. I'm saying, it makes no sense to try and obtain the result set from SQL in this manner. It goes against everything relational theory teaches us.

Comment: @Sherif I see. Yes I understand now. So for now all my queries are ok and I just to make all the processing in the php side?

Comment: @JoeneFloresca the linked topic contains the general way of transposing rows to columns, called pivoting or cross tabulated query. Obviously, you need to write your own formulas to calculate the field values. This is why this topic is a duplicate.

Comment: @Sherif this is a reporting functionality, not a data storage functionality, so this has nothing to do with relational theory. Many RDBMSs natively support some form of pivoting, mysql being a notable exception.

Comment: @Shadow The reporting part has nothing to do with the way in which the resultset is presented. In relational theory there is a distinct purpose behind things like rows and columns and how they are interpreted. Outside of that do with the result set as you please. Just don't conflate the two.

Comment: @Sherif Pls explain this to the developers of oracle, postgresql, ms sql, and ms access, since all of these have built-in support for pivoting. If you search just SO for pivoting related question, you will a lot for all RDBMSs. Using application code to pivot tabular data is **a** solution, but not the only one.

Comment: @Shadow What features those software products support really has nothing to do with this question or my statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the cross table in PHP, as MySql has no support for such pivot format.

With the SQL query you would aim to output something like this:

```
metrics_id  agent_name  score
    1       Chewbacca    1
    1       Luke         0.5
    1       Yoda         0
    2       Chewbacca    1
    2       Luke         1
    2       Yoda         1
    3       Chewbacca    1
    3       Luke         0.5
    3       Yoda         0
```

This can be done with a `select` like this:

```
select     r.metrics_id,
           a.name as agent_name, 
           sum(if(r.response='Yes',1,0))/count(*) as score
from       forms_responses r
cross join agents a
inner join forms f
        on f.id = r.form_id
      and  f.agent_id = a.id
      and  f.calldatetime between '2015-12-12 00:00:00' and '2015-12-17 23:00:37'
      and  f.campaign_id = 22
where      a.id in (
              select agent_id
              from   forms
              where  calldatetime between '2015-12-12 00:00:00' and '2015-12-17 23:00:37'
              and    campaign_id = 22
           )
group by   r.metrics_id, a.name;
```

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/524b1/1).

This query makes sure that you get all the involved agents for every metric, even if for some metric they have not had a response. This makes the processing in PHP a bit easier.

In the PHP you will do the pivoting:

```
$header = array("Metric ID");
$scores = array();
$current_metric = "-1";
$rowno = 0;
$mysqli->query($sql); // SQL as provided above
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // fetch from query
    if ($row["metrics_id"] <> $current_metric) {
        // new metrics_id, start a new line
        $current_metric = $row["metrics_id"];
        $rowno++;
        $scores[$rowno] = array();
        $scores[$rowno][] = $current_metric;
    }
  if ($rowno == 1) {
      $header[] = $row["name"];
  }
  $scores[$rowno][] = $row["score"];
}
// put header row (with agent names) at top of table
array_unshift($scores, $header);

// output table -- you would do this with CSV or Excel library
echo "<table>";
foreach ($scores as $line) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The above would output something like this:

```
Metric ID   Chewbacca   Luke    Yoda
   1           1         0.5     0
   2           1         1       1
   3           1         0.5     0
```

If you prefer to output percentages then you just multiple the score by 100 and add a "%" sign, but note that in Excel this is normally done with formatting, not with the actual number (which stays between 0 and 1).